# What are the best practices when changing activities?

Tags: android

Is there any best practices when changing activities in Android?

It seems very odd to me, just make an Intent and start another activity over and over.

If I just start another activity and finish the last one, when I have to move back, I need to load all the stuff back. But when I don't do it, does not seem to be the right thing to do in terms of memory handling.

Is it correct to save all the activities in a kind of ActivitiesPool or something like this? Or I will always have to choose between keeping them opened or reload them?

Any directions?

Thanks

Comment: The android system itself acts as an "ActivitiesPool". There's basically no reason you should ever instantiate an activity yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems very odd to me, just make an Intent and start another activity over and ove

that's how it works on Android. To be more precise we (as developers) are not even allowed  by the System to call `new Activity()` you just `startActivity(intent);`

> I need to load all the stuff back

again, the framework is taking care of loading/unloading resources as needed

> Is it correct to save all the activities in a kind of ActivitiesPool

no, it's not correct, don't touch them.

If you want the user to be able to click the `back` button and go to the previous activity, DO NOT call `finish();` on it. You can use `onPause()`/`onResume()` callbacks to handle background operations and UI status should be saved on `@Override protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` callback. You put all the UI state that you need in there. If the system needs memory it will destroy the activity and whenever the user is going `back` to it, it will create it again `onCreate(Bundle savedInstances)` and then you'll have all the UI state saved there for you to proper re-create the state where the user was before.

That's how it works.